# laravel move query function from routes to repository

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing

Hi I am pretty new to the world of laravel and I am setting up a repository as I am repeating so many calls to the db so it makes sense to keep it all in one place and refer to this. Anyway I have a chained select which looks at the client_id and finds the matching projects to that client. I have it working in my routes.php file as so:

```
 Route::get('task/clientsprojects', function(){
       $input = Input::get('option');
       $client = Client::find($input);
       $projects =  $projects = Project::where('client_id', $client->id) 
                        ->orderBy('project_name') 
                        ->get(array('id','project_name') 

                        );
   $response = array(); 
   foreach($projects as $project){ 
   $response[$project->id] = $project->project_name; 
  } 

  return Response::json($response);
});
```

I have a this in my create.blade.php file :

```
   <!--These two select boxes are linked together --->
@if(count($client_options)>0)
        {{ Form::select('client', $client_options, Input::old('client'), array('data-placeholder' => 'Choose a Client...', 'id' => 'select_client', 'class' => 'chosen-select tempus_select', 'tabindex' => '2', )) }}
    @endif 

 {{ Form::select('project', array_merge(array('default' => 'Select client first')), 'default', array('class' => 'tempus_select', 'id' => 'project_select')) }}

<script>
$(document).ready(function($){ 
    $('#select_client').change(function(){ 
        $.get("/task/clientsprojects",{ 
            option: $(this).val() 
            }, function(data) { 
            console.log(data); 
            var model = $('#project_select'); 
            model.empty(); 
            $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
$('#project_select').append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>'");
            });
            $("#project_select").trigger("change");
        }); 
    });
});

</script>
```

I've created this function in my repository class:

```
 //fetch clients
public function getClients() 
    {

        return \Auth::user()->clients()->orderBy('client_name', 'asc')->lists('client_name','id');;
    }

 //fetch clients projects
public function getClientsProjects() {

    $input = Input::get('option');
    $client = Client::find($input);

    $projects = $projects = \Auth::user()->projects()->where('client_id', $client->id)->orderBy('project_name')->get(array('id','project_name'));

        $response = array(); 

        foreach($projects as $project){ 
        $response[$project->id] = $project->project_name; 
        } 

        return Response::json($response);
    }
```

My controller refers to the repo as so:

```
<?php
use Acme\Repositories\ProjectRepositoryInterface;
class TaskController extends \BaseController {

    public function __construct(ProjectRepositoryInterface $project) {

        $this->project = $project;

    }

public function create()
{
    //
     $tasks = Auth::user()->tasks;  

    $client_options = $this->project->getClients();


    return View::make('tasks.create', array( 'client_options' => $client_options, 'status' => $status, 'priority' => $priority));
}       

}
```

How can I now route this select to this function to retrieve the data via ajax? Does anyone know how I can proceed? In the above example i am in the task controller and I am fetching my clients in the create function and in the current implementation I have the routes.php catching this and doing the query I want to change it the repo but I am not sure how to implement this.

### Update

I updated my repo to the following:

```
public function getClientsProjects() {

    $input = Input::get('option'); //line 42
    $client = Client::find($input);

$projects =  $projects = Project::where('client_id', $client->id) 
                           ->orderBy('project_name') 
                          ->get(array('id','project_name'));
        $response = array(); 

        foreach($projects as $project){ 
        $response[$project->id] = $project->project_name; 
        } 

        return $response;    
}
```

and inserted the following function to my controller:

```
public function clientsProjects()
{
    return Response::json($this->project->getClientsProjects());
}
```

and this to my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('task/clientsprojects', 'TaskController@clientsProjects');
```

but I get this error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)     
http://tempus.local/task/clientsprojects?option=1
XHR finished loading: GET "http://tempus.local/task/clientsprojects?option=1".
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Laravel Log:

```
[2014-09-03 20:20:45] production.ERROR: exception 
'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 
'Acme\Repositories\Input' not found' in 
/media/sf_Sites/tempus/app/Acme/Repositories/DbProjectRepository.php:42
 Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
 #1 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Well for one thing, in your repo you call the method getClientsProjects, and then you try to call it from your controller using getClients

Comment: getClients is a different call required to load the clients from the clients i want to fetch their projects @MitchGlenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first return only the related data from the repository:

```
public function getClientsProjects($clientId) 
{
    $client = Client::find($clientId);

    ...

    return $response;
}
```

Then change your route to point to your controller:

```
Route::get('task/clientsprojects', 'TaskController@clientsProjects');
```

Then in your controller you do:

```
use Input; /// before your class declaration

...

public function clientsProjects()
{
    $clientId = Input::get('option');

    return Response::json($this->project->getClientsProjects($clientId));
}
```

Comment: ah ok, I've moved this into the places as you've advised but now I am getting errors in the console, I'll post an update @AntonioCarlosRibeiro

Comment: We need the full error message. Take a look at your server log `/var/log/<webservername>` it should tell you what's wrong. And, maybe Laravel too: `/var/www/appdir/app/storage/log/laravel.log`

Comment: You are missing a `use Input` at the top of your repository.

Comment: Edited to make it look better in terms of design. I removed the Input from the repository and transferred it to the controller, passing the client id to the controller via method parameter.

Comment: do you know how I can implement a placeholder on my select dropdown `@if(count($client_options)>0) {{ Form::select('client', $client_options, Input::old('client'), array('data-placeholder' => 'Choose a Client...', 'id' => 'select_client', 'class' => 'chosen-select tempus_select', 'tabindex' => '2', )) }} @endif` the placeholder here makes no difference

Comment: Try doing it in HTML first, if it works (not sure if it does), should be easy do do it in Laravel too. But usually people add a first element with value = 0.

Comment: how would I add a first element in blade? or would i would jQuery or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60578/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-g-9020).